# Issues with a VBA For Next loop not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to wrap my head around a piece of code that has worked for me in the past not working right now in a different application. Basically it needs to delete all rows that contain information in a specific column and leave the rest untouched. When I run the macro the code executes without issues, but just deletes some of the rows with values, not all of them. When running the code several times in a row it ends up doing what it is intended, but it's really not convenient. Here is the code:

```
Sub Delete_Signoffed()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer


Worksheets("MilestoneDueDate").Activate
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A")) = 0 Then
    Columns("A").Delete
    Rows("1:6").Delete
End If

iCol = Cells.Find("Sign-Off By", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

For iRow = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) Then Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
Next iRow

End Sub
```

The source file has some formatting issues, everything that comes before assigning iCol the column value is to fix the format, so please ignore. iRow starts at 2 to avoid deleting the file headers.

Any ideas on why the For loop is not working as intended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always loop backwards when deleting. Plenty of examples around.

Comment: You can also use `Join` to join all the rows you want to delete and then delete them at once. Plenty of examples of that option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your script. I also added comments for you to be able to understand it better and able to improve it in the future.

```
Sub Delete_Signoffed()

'Goto CleanUp if there are errors
On Error GoTo CleanUp

Dim wsMilestoneDueDate As Worksheet

Dim rCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer

Set wsMilestoneDueDate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MilestoneDueDate")

'Disable temporarily Screen Updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wsMilestoneDueDate
    
    .Activate   'No need, but if you prefer you can
    
    'Activate Auto Filter
    If .AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
    
    'Remove FreezePanes
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    
    'Unhide Columns
    .Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
    'Delete Empty Columns/Rows if they are all empty
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns("A")) = 0 Then
        Columns("A").Delete
        Rows("1:6").Delete
    End If
    
    'Get the last Column
    iCol = .UsedRange.Find("Sign-Off By", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    
    'Start Deleting but from the last to the first (Backward)
    For iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        
        Set rCell = Cells(iRow, iCol)
        
        'Delete the entire row if it is NOT empty
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            'Deletion
            Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next iRow
    
End With

CleanUp:
    'Purge Memory
    Set wsMilestoneDueDate = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing

    'Restore Screen Updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in comments, the flaw in your code was not looping backwards

But I hereby give you a solution without looping and using one line only, thanks to `SpecialCells` method of `Range` object, specifying it to filter cells with some "constant" (i.e. not deriving from formulas) value

```
    Range(Cells(2, iCol), Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
```

this assumes you always have at least one value below row 1

should not that be the case then just add a check:

```
    If Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then Range(Cells(2, iCol), Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
```

While looking at your entire code you should adopt the good practice to avoid `Select/Selection, Activate/ActiveXXX` pattern and Always fully qualify ranges up to their worksheet (if not workbook) parent objects, like follows:

```
Sub Delete_Signoffed()

    Dim iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("MilestoneDueDate") ' reference wanted sheet

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

        .Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns("A")) = 0 Then
            .Columns("A").Delete
            .Rows("1:6").Delete
        End If

        iCol = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find("Sign-Off By", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Column

        .Range(.Cells(2, iCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete

    End With   

End Sub
```

as you can see

- all range objects (`Columns()`, `Rows`, `Range`, `Cells`) are referencing `Worksheets("MilestoneDueDate")` through that dot (`.`) in front of them
- `iCol` is being set running `Find()` method in the most restricted range possibile